# LINQ - Dynamically Invoke ToDictionary

Tags: .net, linq, dictionary, reflection

Is there a way in `.Net` to dynamically invoke `ToDictionary(<lambda key>, <lambda val>)` to reduce boilerplate of returning a `Dictionary` when running LINQ expressions.

C# Example:

```
Dictionary<string, object> d_filt;

Dictionary<string, object> d_in = new Dictionary<string, object>();
d_in.Add("k1", 4);
d_in.Add("k2", 3);
d_in.Add("k3", 2);
d_in.Add("k4", 1);

// Current Expression:
d_filt = d_in.Where(p => p.value > 2)
             .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);

// Preferred Expression:
d_filt = linq2Dict(d_in.Where(p => p.value > 2));
```

Where `linq2Dict(<LinqObj>)` is a helper that will dynamically invoke the  `ToDictionary(..)` method.

I have tried Reflection library but it appears that `ToDictionary` is not available through the standard Reflection library I'm familiar with.

Note: VB is even more verbose:

```
Dim d_filt = d_in.Where(Function(p) p.value > 2).ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Key, Function(p) p.Value)
```

Of course, the slickest solution would be to add a `ToDict()` `Extension` which took no arguments resulting in:

```
// Preferred Expression:
d_filt = d_in.Where(p => p.value > 2).ToDict()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reflection is necessary, just plain ol' generic

```
public static class Convert
{
    public static Dictionary<T,U> ToDict<T,U>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,U>> source) where T : notnull
    {
        return source.ToDictionary(s=>s.Key,s=>s.Value);
    }
}
```

The constraint for T is because Dictionary can't use null keys.

As a bonus it maintains the fluent syntax, so you can just use

```
d_filt = d_in.Where(p => p.value > 2).ToDict();
```

Comment: This code is very sexy

Comment: Excellent! Any chance you can covert this to VB? Its not cleanly converting for me.

Comment: Figured it out: Module Convert
    <Extension()>
    Function ToDict(Of T, U)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of T, U))) As Dictionary(Of T, U)
        Return source.ToDictionary(Function(s) s.Key, Function(s) s.Value)
    End Function
End Module

Comment: @TimothyC.Quinn You can post that as another answer, make it easier for others to adopt.

Comment: Added VB example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To build on [@Martheen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72691365/286807), here is how to implement ToDict() extension in VB:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Convert
    <Extension()>
    Function ToDict(Of T, U)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of T, U))) As Dictionary(Of T, U)
        Return source.ToDictionary(Function(s) s.Key, Function(s) s.Value)
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of `linq2Dict()` in VB:

```
Public Shared Function linq2Dict(Of T, U)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of T, U))) As Dictionary(Of T, U)
    Return source.ToDictionary(Function(s) s.Key, Function(s) s.Value)
End Function
```

Eg:

```
d_filt = linq2Dict(d_in.Where(p => p.value > 2))
```